# Quantum Computer Basics

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, superposition

I am a newbie to Quantum Computing world. My collage professor asked me to do presentation on quantum computing. I have read many articles online but still I think I am not satisfied with what I found. So, my question is for superposition and entanglement.

I have read it somewhere that superposition is not $0$ and $1$ at the same time, but some probability of being $0$ and some probability of being at the same time.

So how do we write information on qubits so it stays on the superposition?
How does superposition allow us to store more information then classical bits?
How does the quantum computer process qubits?

**Entanglement**
From few articles I read online, I found that qubits can be entangled with [CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) and also they can be entangled by Spontaneous parametric down-conversion (SPDC) method. Which one is preferred currently?

Entangling qubits means that any change made on one qubit instantaneously affects the other.

So, any information change on the qubit being processed inside quantum computers will also change the information of qubits entangled.

So how does entangling qubits really help us to solve large problems?
How do we use entanglement on quantum computers and how does it increase it's computing power?
Does two entangled qubits store more information then two individual qubits? If yes, then how?\

How are entangled qubits processed inside a quantum computer?

It would be grateful if you can provide some information on **Quantum Error Correction**

I hope this question doesn't annoy you as it's too basic, and I apologize for my grammatical mistakes.\

Any extra information is welcomed. It would be a great help for my presentation.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You can edit the question to make it on-topic and it will trigger a reopen vote